# Select maximum value from database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I have database with row `myDate   |   string`

myDate is Date with format `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. How to select newest date for example, I have:

```
2011-08-26 14:14:51
```

and

```
2011-09-21 12:25:45
```

And I need select statement to select last date (`2011-09-21 12:25:45`). Please help me to write select statement..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the dates are stored similar to the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, the lexicographical order corresponds to the chronological order. So you can just use [`MAX`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#minggunc):

```
SELECT MAX(myDate) FROM your_table
```

Comment: Just tried this, It's returning "myDate" against `2011-09-21 12:25:45`. May be I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You're probably surrounding the column name in quotation marks which  the database regards as a request for that literal string of characters: `select 'foo' from T` will get you the result "foo" even if there's a column named [foo] in table T.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job :

`SELECT MAX(myDate) FROM <yourtable>`